# Error in Python: not arguments fully converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql

My query is:

```
z = request.session['username']
cursord.execute("delete from table where column = %s",z)
```

Getting error as not arguments fully converted during string formatting.

> query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args]) TypeError:
>   not all arguments converted during string formatting "GET /logout/
>   HTTP/1.1" 500 68562

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to post the complete error stack trace as it will be easy to debug.

Comment: what is print(z), z might not be the string your are expecting

Comment: z is printing as username

Comment: z is printing john.11@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a tuple:

```
cursord.execute("delete from table where column = %s", (z,))
```

If you really are using django, the correct way to logout someone from the session is to use the `logout` view, as detailed [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out).

Comment: i tried that but its giving programming error.   ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table = 'username' ' at line 1")

Comment: That's another problem and nothing to do with Python.

Comment: Thanks Burhan but why need to pass tuple?

Comment: its because you need to pass in positional arguments.